# awk sub() not doing replacement

Tags: string, awk, replace

The example text file.

## in2.txt file:

```
*{commented out line}* KeyWordName = KeyWordValueAA  
KeyWordName = KeyWordValueAA
```

The regexp finds the string:

```
awk '/^KeyWordName[[:blank:]]=[[:blank:]].*$/' in2.txt
```

## Output:

```
KeyWordName = KeyWordValueAA
```

## Command that results in no errors or changed text:

```
awk '{sub(/^KeyWordName[[:blank:]]=[[:blank:]].*$/, "KeyWordValueBB")}' in2.txt
```

Removing the double quotes does not work either.
Reading the manpage did not help either.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of `KeyWordName` in the second line to `KeyWordValueBB`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly print to see any output:

A common awk idiom is to add a `1` after the action:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^KeyWordName[[:blank:]]=[[:blank:]].*$/, "KeyWordValueBB")}1' file
{commented out line} KeyWordName = KeyWordValueAA
KeyWordValueBB
```

The `1` is an always-true pattern and since there's no corresponding action, the default action of `print` is performed (on *all* input lines).

Or you can just use `print`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^KeyWordName[[:blank:]]=[[:blank:]].*$/, "KeyWordValueBB")} {print}' file
{commented out line} KeyWordName = KeyWordValueAA
KeyWordValueBB
```

To change the file when you don't have the `-i` option, save to a temporary file and rename it to your file (that's what `-i` is doing for you, anyway). By using `&&` we are sure the `mv` command will only be executed if the `awk` terminates with success. Stil, *you might want to save a copy of your original file first* in case the `awk` is "successful" from the OS point of view, but doesn't do what you expected!

```
awk '{ ... }' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks that showed me that the regexp and replacement are working. But I need to change the file in2.txt, not the buffer.

Comment: Thanks that showed me that the regexp and replacement are working. But I need to change the file in2.txt, not the buffer.  My version of awk does not take the awk -i inplace parm.

Comment: See the update to my answer for how to change the file.

Comment: Since the code must run in the IBM AIX OS below is what had to be used.    # Perform keyword value replacement.  
awk '{sub("^KeyWordName[[:blank:]]=[[:blank:]].*$", "KeyWordName = KeyWordValueBB")} {print}' in2.txt >>  in3.txt   
# Perform keyword value replacement.  
# vi in2.txt  
# vi in3.txt  
# Overwrite the original file with the new output file from awk  
mv in3.txt in2.txt